# Sorting array by parent / recurse

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, parent

I have SQL query that returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 0
            [name] => Strona Główna
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 1
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 0
            [name] => Podstrona strony głównej
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 2015
            [name] => O nas
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent] => 1
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 2015
            [name] => Kolejna podstrona
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent] => 3
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 0
            [name] => Kolejna podstrona
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [parent] => 5
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 0
            [name] => tuytuytuyt
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent] => 5
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 0
            [name] => fghfhgfh
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
        )

)
```

And I've almost successfully made it to sort. If element has a parent, it creates an array and put children to this element, but there's a problem with last elements and I dunno why.

Now output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 0
            [name] => Strona Główna
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
            [node] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [parent] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2015
                            [updated_at] => 0
                            [name] => Podstrona strony głównej
                            [short] => 
                            [content] => 
                            [header] => 
                            [img] => 
                            [visible] => 0
                            [position] => 1000
                            [top] => 0
                            [left] => 0
                            [footer] => 0
                            [dropdown] => 0
                            [chilldren] => 0
                            [title] => 
                            [description] => 
                            [keywords] => 
                            [tags] => 
                            [redirect] => 
                            [js] => 
                            [css] => 
                            [css_class] => 
                            [module] => 
                            [lang] => 0
                            [node] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [parent] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2015
                            [updated_at] => 2015
                            [name] => Kolejna podstrona
                            [short] => 
                            [content] => 
                            [header] => 
                            [img] => 
                            [visible] => 0
                            [position] => 1000
                            [top] => 0
                            [left] => 0
                            [footer] => 0
                            [dropdown] => 0
                            [chilldren] => 0
                            [title] => 
                            [description] => 
                            [keywords] => 
                            [tags] => 
                            [redirect] => 
                            [js] => 
                            [css] => 
                            [css_class] => 
                            [module] => 
                            [lang] => 0
                            [node] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 8
                                            [parent] => 5
                                            [created_at] => 2015
                                            [updated_at] => 0
                                            [name] => tuytuytuyt
                                            [short] => 
                                            [content] => 
                                            [header] => 
                                            [img] => 
                                            [visible] => 0
                                            [position] => 1000
                                            [top] => 0
                                            [left] => 0
                                            [footer] => 0
                                            [dropdown] => 0
                                            [chilldren] => 0
                                            [title] => 
                                            [description] => 
                                            [keywords] => 
                                            [tags] => 
                                            [redirect] => 
                                            [js] => 
                                            [css] => 
                                            [css_class] => 
                                            [module] => 
                                            [lang] => 0
                                            [node] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9
                                            [parent] => 5
                                            [created_at] => 2015
                                            [updated_at] => 0
                                            [name] => fghfhgfh
                                            [short] => 
                                            [content] => 
                                            [header] => 
                                            [img] => 
                                            [visible] => 0
                                            [position] => 1000
                                            [top] => 0
                                            [left] => 0
                                            [footer] => 0
                                            [dropdown] => 0
                                            [chilldren] => 0
                                            [title] => 
                                            [description] => 
                                            [keywords] => 
                                            [tags] => 
                                            [redirect] => 
                                            [js] => 
                                            [css] => 
                                            [css_class] => 
                                            [module] => 
                                            [lang] => 0
                                            [node] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 1
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 0
            [name] => Podstrona strony głównej
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
            [node] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 2015
            [name] => O nas
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
            [node] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [parent] => 3
                            [created_at] => 2015
                            [updated_at] => 0
                            [name] => Kolejna podstrona
                            [short] => 
                            [content] => 
                            [header] => 
                            [img] => 
                            [visible] => 0
                            [position] => 1000
                            [top] => 0
                            [left] => 0
                            [footer] => 0
                            [dropdown] => 0
                            [chilldren] => 0
                            [title] => 
                            [description] => 
                            [keywords] => 
                            [tags] => 
                            [redirect] => 
                            [js] => 
                            [css] => 
                            [css_class] => 
                            [module] => 
                            [lang] => 0
                            [node] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent] => 1
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 2015
            [name] => Kolejna podstrona
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
            [node] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                            [parent] => 5
                            [created_at] => 2015
                            [updated_at] => 0
                            [name] => tuytuytuyt
                            [short] => 
                            [content] => 
                            [header] => 
                            [img] => 
                            [visible] => 0
                            [position] => 1000
                            [top] => 0
                            [left] => 0
                            [footer] => 0
                            [dropdown] => 0
                            [chilldren] => 0
                            [title] => 
                            [description] => 
                            [keywords] => 
                            [tags] => 
                            [redirect] => 
                            [js] => 
                            [css] => 
                            [css_class] => 
                            [module] => 
                            [lang] => 0
                            [node] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [parent] => 5
                            [created_at] => 2015
                            [updated_at] => 0
                            [name] => fghfhgfh
                            [short] => 
                            [content] => 
                            [header] => 
                            [img] => 
                            [visible] => 0
                            [position] => 1000
                            [top] => 0
                            [left] => 0
                            [footer] => 0
                            [dropdown] => 0
                            [chilldren] => 0
                            [title] => 
                            [description] => 
                            [keywords] => 
                            [tags] => 
                            [redirect] => 
                            [js] => 
                            [css] => 
                            [css_class] => 
                            [module] => 
                            [lang] => 0
                            [node] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent] => 3
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 0
            [name] => Kolejna podstrona
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
            [node] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [parent] => 5
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 0
            [name] => tuytuytuyt
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
            [node] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent] => 5
            [created_at] => 2015
            [updated_at] => 0
            [name] => fghfhgfh
            [short] => 
            [content] => 
            [header] => 
            [img] => 
            [visible] => 0
            [position] => 1000
            [top] => 0
            [left] => 0
            [footer] => 0
            [dropdown] => 0
            [chilldren] => 0
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [tags] => 
            [redirect] => 
            [js] => 
            [css] => 
            [css_class] => 
            [module] => 
            [lang] => 0
            [node] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see last elements are not filtered.

Code for "sorting" parent's looks like:

```
            $new = [];
            foreach($data as $key => $item) {
              $data[$key] - > node = [];
              array_push($new, $data[$key]);

              for ($i = 0; $i < count($new); $i++) {
                if ($new[$i] - > id == $data[$key] - > parent) {
                  array_push($new[$i] - > node, $data[$key]);
                }

              }
            }

            print_r($data);
```

Can anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is wrong with the last elements in your output? nodes with id 6, 8 and 9 have no children, so they appear alone, which I would find normal. Can you add to your question the output you wanted to have?

Comment: They belong to specific "parent" and as u can see i do not want and i dont work with "children" key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function, like this:

```
function makeTree($data, $parent) {
    $tree = [];
    foreach($data as $item) {
        if ($item -> parent == $parent) {
            $item -> node = makeTree($data, $item -> id);
            $tree[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

$new = makeTree($data, null);

print_r($new);
```

This function makes a tree of all descendants of the given parent. The recursion stops when an element has no children, and then the function returns an empty array.

The return value of the function (an array) is used by the caller, to add it to the `node` property of the parent node.

The function is called first by the root value, i.e. the value you assign to the `parent` property when there is no parent. In your case is this is `null`, so that is why the main call has `null` as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over the results, you should ask if the current element has a parent. If the element has no parent, then simply add the element to the new array, but if the element has a parent then add it to the node list of that element:

```
$new = [];
foreach($data as $key => $item) {    
  if(!empty($item->parent)) 
    $new[$item->id]->node[]= $item;
  else
    $new[$item->id]= $item;
}
print_r($data);
```

Of course this will work only if the parent of an element comes before that element in the result set.

Comment: Your code does not resolve my problem. It generates the same result as I quoted at begin of my question, but the only one difference is that it takes element with parent and is sending it below new created "node".